# Hi, I have with problems with cx_freeze and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to convert a tkinter project to an exe but when I run setup.py i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tiago\Desktop\Python\Calculator\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":[tkinter],"include_files":["Calculator.ico"]}},
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

Can someone says whats the problem with my code?

```
import cx_Freeze

executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("Calculator.pyw")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Calculator",
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":[tkinter],"include_files":["Calculator.ico"]}},
    description = "Calculator",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `"tkinter"` instead of `tkinter`.

But in most cases tkinter will be included automatically if you import `tkinter` in a normal way in your script. So you can just delete `"packages":["tkinter"]`.

Btw you might need to declare your executable as `Win32GUI` program in this way:

```
executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("Calculator.pyw", base='Win32GUI')]
```

Comment: Thx for answering